# Adding a random offset to drivers

Tags: python, animation, scripting, bezier-curves, drivers

So I want to animate multiple "cables" (witch are curves), i want to animate the bevel start (or end) and add a random offset to this value. I could put some keyframes and offset them manually but i got a lot of curves.

1. Is there is a more efficient way to do it ?
2. Is it possible ?
3. Is it possible to create drivers for an object with pyton ?

I've made a blend file with my progress so far : [curves+python blend file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14fsl-5EPn9ID-rNZJL6hKztfNoNb02sO)

Thanks for any help

Edit : I could create multiple cable object and add to each object a curve modifier (how to link it to one object ?)and offset them randomly (I know how to do it), and animate them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my script so it also add the random offset for the animation

```
import bpy
import random

i = 0
depth = 0.1
resolution = 8


def blenderNumber(number):
    if number == 0:
        return ("")

    else:
        if number < 10:
            return ("00{0}".format(number))
        elif number < 100:
            return ("0{0}".format(number))
        elif number <1000:
            return (number)


while i < 50:
    if i == 0:
        frameRandom = 50

        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].fill_mode = "FULL"
        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].bevel_depth = depth
        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].bevel_resolution = resolution

        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].bevel_factor_start = 1
        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].keyframe_insert(data_path = "bevel_factor_start", frame = 0)

        frameRandom += random.randint(-20,20)
        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].bevel_factor_start = 0
        bpy.data.curves["Mesh"].keyframe_insert(data_path = "bevel_factor_start", frame = frameRandom)



    else:
        frameRandom = 30

        tempMeshName = '%(Mname)s.%(Mnumber)s' % {'Mname': "Mesh", "Mnumber": blenderNumber(i)}
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].fill_mode = "FULL"
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].bevel_depth = depth
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].bevel_resolution= resolution

        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].bevel_factor_start = 1
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].keyframe_insert(data_path = "bevel_factor_start", frame = 0)

        frameRandom += random.randint(-20,20)
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].bevel_factor_start = 0
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].keyframe_insert(data_path = "bevel_factor_start", frame = frameRandom)
        bpy.data.curves[tempMeshName].keyframe_delete

    i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Am using "Commotion Add-on" for random offset effects. That should be the best Add-on to handle that

Comment: Thanks ! I’ll give it a try.